# Computing the arc length of a cycloid

Tags: calculus

I have been doing [this exercise](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-vectors-and-matrices/part-c-parametric-equations-for-curves/session-20-velocity-and-arc-length/MIT18_02SC_we_11_comb.pdf).

What is being done after this?

> which implies $$\left|\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right|=\ldots$$

How do I get to $$2a\sqrt{\sin^2(\theta/2)}?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\left|\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right|^2 = 4a^2\left(\sin^4(\theta/2) + \sin^2(\theta/2)\cos^2(\theta/2)\right) \\= 4a^2\sin^2(\theta/2)\left(\sin^2(\theta/2) + \cos^2(\theta/2)\right) = 4a^2\sin^2(\theta/2)$$

where we have used $\cos^2x + \sin^2 x = 1$.